# What is this icon above the Emancipation Gate (in Civilization Beyond Earth)

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I was playing Civilization Beyond Earth and the game crashed.  Around that time the icon denoted by red arrows appeared.  The square denoted by the green arrow appears when the cursor is above the other icon.  Every time I open this save file (even after reinstall or on a different machine) the icons appear.  The Emancipation Gate was owned by ARC.  I am unsure if it is a bug, since I can't find the icon anywhere else in the game, but it looks like someone drew it (that is, that it isn't random noise like one would expect with a game/GPU glitch).

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but perhaps it means that its active and thus available to send military units into for a game victory?

Comment: oo..  good idea.  I didn't notice that in my emancipation gate, but I'll check net time.